# how to fetch images from database through image id

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have done a gallery page by fetching images from a database. Now I have to view a particular image in that page. For that I need to set id for the particular image to view. What is the code to view image through id?

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie7 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie8 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en-gb" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>Image Dental Clinic</title> 

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- **Favicon** -->
    <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- **CSS - stylesheets** -->
    <link id="default-css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link id="shortcodes-css" href="shortcodes.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

    <link id="skin-css" href="skins/green/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />    

    <link id="fancy-box" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />    

    <!-- **Additional - stylesheets** -->
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link href="css/pace-theme-loading-bar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />


    <!-- **Font Awesome** -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon.css">

    <!-- **Google - Fonts** -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- **Modernizr** -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mytheme_urls = {
        stickynav : 'enable'
    };
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <!--<div id="loader-wrapper">
        <div class="loader">
            <span class="glyph-icon flaticon-man159"></span>
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <!-- **Wrapper** -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <!-- header-wrapper starts here -->
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <header id="header">
                    <!-- Top bar starts here -->
                    <div class="top-bar">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="dt-sc-contact-info">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Any Questions? Call Us: <span>966 1 4836060</span></p>
                            </div>
                           <!-- <div class="top-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a title="Login" href="login.html"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>Member Login</a></li>
                                    <li><a title="Register Now" href="register.html"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Register </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Top bar ends here -->
                    <div class="main-menu-container">
          <div class="main-menu">
            <div id="logo"> <a title="Travel" href="index.html"><img title="Fitness" alt="Fitness" src="images/logo.png"></a> </div>
            <div id="primary-menu">
              <div class="dt-menu-toggle" id="dt-menu-toggle">Menu<span class="dt-menu-toggle-icon"></span></div>
              <nav id="main-menu">
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                  <li class="menu-item-simple-parent menu-item-depth-0"><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
                  <li class="menu-item-megamenu-parent  megamenu-4-columns-group menu-item-depth-0"> <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
                   </li>
                  <li class="menu-item-simple-parent menu-item-depth-0"><a href="service.php">Our Services </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                       <li> <a href="cosmetic_dentistry.php">Cosmetic Dentistry </span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="dental_implant.php">Dental Implants </span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="periodontal_care.php">Periodontal Care</span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="endodontic_treatment.php">Endodontic Treatment </span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="pediatric_dentistry.php">Pediatric Dentistry </span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="orthodontics.php">Orthodontics </span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="restorative_dentistry.php">Restorative Dentistry </span> </span> </a> </li>

                    </ul>
                    <a class="dt-menu-expand">+</a> </li>

                  <li class="menu-item-megamenu-parent  megamenu-4-columns-group menu-item-depth-0"> <a href="doctors.php" title="">Doctors</a> </li>
                  <li class="menu-item-megamenu-parent  megamenu-4-columns-group menu-item-depth-0"> <a href="appoinment.php" title="">Appoinment</a> </li>

                  <li class="current_page_item menu-item-megamenu-parent  megamenu-4-columns-group menu-item-depth-0"> <a href="gallery.php" title=""> Gallery </a> </li>

                  <li class="menu-item-simple-parent menu-item-depth-0"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
            </div>
            <!-- header-wrapper ends here -->
            <!-- breadcrumb starts here -->
            <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Gallery</h1>
                    <div class="breadcrumb">
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        <span class="default">  </span>
                        <h4>Gallery</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- breadcrumb ends here -->
            <div id="main">
                <!-- main-content starts here -->
                <div id="main-content">
                    <section id="primary" class="content-full-width">
                        <div class="dt-sc-hr-invisible"></div>
                        <div class="dt-sc-hr-invisible-small"></div>
                        <div class="container">




                            <div class="dt-sc-portfolio-container">
                            <?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345"); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("icareimage"); 
//MySQL Query to read data

$query = mysql_query("SELECT photo FROM photos WHERE  type='gallery'", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))         
{?>
                                <div class="portfolio dt-sc-one-third column flexibility games">
                                    <div class="portfolio-thumb">

                                <?php echo' <img src="images/photos/'.$row["photo"].'"/>'; ?>


                                          <div class="image-overlay">
                                            <div class="fig-content-wrapper">
                                                <div class="fig-overlay">


        <p>

                             <a href="" class="zoom" >   <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span></a>

                                             </p>    

                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                      </div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                               <?php } ?>                  
                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </section>
                       </div>

                       </div>

                        <!-- support starts here -->
                         <!-- paralax starts here -->
          <div class="fullwidth-section full-man">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="dt-sc-one-half column first animate" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="100">
                <h3 class="section-title">Make an Appointment</h3>
                <div id="ajax_contact_msg"></div>
                <form name="frmcontact" action="#" method="post" id="contact-form">
                  <div class="dt-sc-one-half column first">
                    <input type="text" name="txtname" placeholder="Enter name..." required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dt-sc-one-half column">
                    <input type="email" name="txtemail" placeholder="Enter email..." required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dt-sc-one-half column first">
                    <input type="text" name="txtname" placeholder="Enter Phone..." required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dt-sc-one-half column">
                    <input type="email" name="txtemail" placeholder="Select Date..." required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <div class="selection-box">
                    <select name="cmbsubject">
                      <option value="Ask a Question?">Select Treatment</option>
                      <option value="">Cosmetic Dentistry</option>
                      <option value="">Dental Implants</option>
                       <option value="">Periodontal Care</option>
                        <option value="">Endodontic Treatment</option>
                         <option value="">Pediatric Dentistry</option>
                          <option value="">Orthodontics</option>
                          <option value="">Restorative Dentistry</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                   <div class="selection-box">
                    <select name="cmbsubject">
                      <option value="Ask a Question?">What time you would like to come in</option>
                      <option value="">Morning</option>
                      <option value="">Afternoon</option>
                       <option value="">Evening</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <textarea name="txtmessage" placeholder="Type your queries..." required></textarea>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Query">
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="dt-sc-one-half column"> <img src="images/man.png" alt="" title="" class="aligncenter"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- paralax ends here -->

                    </section>
                </div>
                                 <!-- Team starts here -->




          </div>
          <!-- Team ends here -->
                <!-- main-content ends here -->
            </div>
            <div class="dt-sc-hr-invisible-medium"></div>
            <!-- footer starts here -->
             <footer id="footer">
      <div class="footer-widgets-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth first">
            <aside class="widget widget_text">
              <div class="textwidget">
                <h3 class="widgettitle"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>About Us</h3>
                <p>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,  making it look like readable English. </p>
                <p>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</p>
              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>
          <div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth">
            <aside class="widget widget_text">
              <h3 class="widgettitle"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>Ouick Links</h3>
              <div class="textwidget">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="packages.php">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="appoinment.php">Appoinment</a></li>
                  <li><a href="gallery.php">Galery</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>
          <div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth">
            <aside class="widget widget_text">
              <h3 class="widgettitle"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>Our Services</h3>
              <div class="textwidget">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="cosmetic_dentistry.php">Cosmetic Dentistry</a></li>
                  <li><a href="dental_implant.php">Dental Implants</a></li>
                  <li><a href="periodontal_care.php">Periodontal Care</a></li>
                  <li><a href="endodontic_treatment.php">Endodontic Treatment</a></li>
                  <li><a href="pediatric_dentistry.php">Pediatric Dentistry</a></li>
                   <li> <a href="orthodontics.php">Orthodontics </span> </span> </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="restorative_dentistry.php">Restorative Dentistry </span> </span> </a> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>
          <div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth">
            <aside class="widget widget_recent_entries">
              <h3 class="widgettitle"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>Contact Us</h3>
             <!-- <div class="recent-posts-widget">
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="#" class="entry-thumb"><img src="images/blog-thumb.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
                    <h4><a href="#">Training with Dumbell</a></h4>
                    <div class="entry-metadata">
                      <p class="date">26 May 2014</p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" class="entry-thumb"><img src="images/blog-thumb1.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
                    <h4><a href="#">Create the Adonis Effect</a></h4>
                    <div class="entry-metadata">
                      <p class="date">24 May 2014</p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>-->

              <div class="textwidget">

                <p>Image Dental clinic<br/>
                Riyadh - Specialist Street<br/>
                Tel : +966 1 4836060<br/>
                Fax : +966 1 483770<br/>
                 </p>

              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-media-container">
          <div class="social-media">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="dt-sc-contact-info dt-phone">
                <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span>966 1 4836060</span> </p>
              </div>
              <ul class="dt-sc-social-icons">
                <li class="facebook"><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                <li class="google"><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                <li class="twitter"><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                <li class="youtube"><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                <li class="rss"><a href="#" class="fa fa-rss"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="about.php"> About Us </a></li>
            <li><a href="service.php"> Services </a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php"> Contact Us </a></li>
          </ul>
          <p>&copy; 2015 - Image Dental Clinic</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: no errors. i need to view image in full screen while click on image thumbnail . <a href="" class="zoom" >   <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span></a>...but problem is i want to fetch from database by the help of $id

Comment: are you saving image in database or just image name in database?

Comment: image name in database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28762905/3989103

Answer (score 1):

```
//using image name
mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxxxxx");
mysql_select_db("wellho");
$image = stripslashes($_REQUEST[imname]);
$rs = mysql_query("select * from im_library where filename=\"".
        addslashes($image).".jpg\"");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$imagebytes = $row[imgdata];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $imagebytes;


//using image Id
include 'inc/db.php';

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
$image = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM sites WHERE id = '$id'");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id={$id}");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo "<img src='images/$result["image_columnname"]' />";
```